# How to read a text file and store data in an array

Tags: lua

I want to read data from a txt file, and store it in an array, so I can index it. The text file is something like this:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
```

The data will be stored in an array like `temp`, so then I can index the specific value by `temp(0)`, can anyone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

The code below is a variation of the one given by Yu Hao. It is simpler and does not leave any file open after the loop: [f:lines()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:lines) does not close the file when the loop ends.

```
local temp = {}
for line in io.lines("t.txt") do
    table.insert(temp, tonumber(line))
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
local f = io.open("t.txt")
local temp = {}
for line in f:lines() do
    table.insert(temp, tonumber(line))
end
```

Note that in Lua, arrays use index starting from `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "*a" ,read function, it should read the whole file for example , to store each line in an array you can use use io:lines () - where each call gives you a new line , Hope this helps

```
local file = io.open("your-file-name", "r");
local data = file:read("*a")
local file = io.open("file-name", "r");
 local arr = {}
 for line in file:lines() do
    table.insert (arr, line);
 end
```